# Mapbox: How to show Driving/Cycling/Walking options

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox

How to show Driving/Cycling/Walking options in Android?
I know setting the profile will change the way directions are shown but I want to provide to the user direction options in the UI. Is it possible in Android like the picture below?

[Directions options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK68V.png)

It seems according to this question [Unable to hide profile ui (Traffic, Driving, Walking, Cycling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157474/unable-to-hide-profile-ui-traffic-driving-walking-cycling) that should be a profile switcher in controls. But I didn't find it in Android.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for checking out the Mapbox SDKs!  Unfortunately, we don't have a pre-built Android UI for selecting direction options like the picture you linked - you would need to build your own UI in your app code.  Sorry for the inconvenience